# PHP GET request on domainname that is not yet resolved (ip is known)

Tags: php, curl, dns

I have a hosting account with a domain, the domain not yet resolved to the IP address (not inserted DNS records yet). I know the IP of the server, and the domain is configured on the server.
Now I want to get the content of the website using PHP (with curl for example).
On my (windows) computer I can simply edit the hosts (windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts) file to achieve this, but how can this be achieved within a PHP-script?

Backtground information:
I need to run a PHP script on a hosting account where the domainname is under registry. I use DirectAdmin on my own server, and normally the website will also be visible under ipaddress/~username. But as the server is on suPHP strict settings it will not run PHP-code that way. As the script should be working on any webserver, adjusting the suPHP settings to allow this is no option

Answer (score 0):

You could directly use the IP address of the Web Server with manually formed "Host" request header value as your domain name which is under registry.

Assuming your domain name is **foo-test.com**, it is yet to be added to DNS record but already  virtually hosted in a Web Server who is IP address is **1.1.1.1**.

(Below example uses command line **curl** HTTP client)

```
curl --header "Host: foo-test.com" "http://1.1.1.1"
```

(Note: Host header value is used by Web Server to identify the virtually hosted Web Sites)